# Communities: Redirect from one domain to another

Tags: community, custom-domain

I have a community setup and recently added a custom url to move from the `sitea.force.com` url schema to our own domain of ourdomain.org.

For instance, I added the new custom domain of `siteb.ourdomain.org` and the community is accessible at that address. I want to redirect all users coming in to `sitea.force.com` to the new URL at `siteb.ourdomain.org`. How can I do this? The site redirect rules won't quite do this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a javascript redirect.

For a Visual Force community, create the following  Visual Force page and set it as the home page:

```
<apex:page>
  <script>
    window.location='http://www.google.com';
  </script>
</apex:page>
```

For a lightning community, create the following component and put it on the home page:

*the lightning component*

```
<aura:component>
  <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>    
</aura:component>
```

*the lightning client side controller*

```
({
   doInit: function(cmp) {
     window.location='http://www.google.com';
   }
})
```

For the above examples, you replace the url with your own custom url.

Comment: I just saw this. This is exactly what I ended up doing yesterday. I just stuck the code in an existing component, though. Not what I really wanted to do, as I figured there was a better way to do it, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can create `Login` flow and attached the flow in the user's profile. Refer [Set Up a Login Flow and Connect to Profiles](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_login_flow_associate.htm)

In the `LoginFlow_FinishLocation` variable, specify your new URL `siteb.ourdomain.org`.

It should work.

For more information, refer [Login flow examples](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_login_flow_examples.htm)